# Font style is not preserved when converting HTML to PDF using ItextSharp

Tags: c#, html, pdf

I'm trying to convert HTML to PDF, but the font style isn't being properly applied to the PDF. Below is my code (using `itextsharp.dll`):

```
Document document = new Document();
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
document.Open();
HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
string content = radEditorCollector.Content;
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content))
{
    content = AppConstants.LetterNotConfigured;
}
htmlWorker.Parse(new StringReader(content));
document.Close();
fs.Close();
//Create document list of each debtor
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);
readerList.Add(pdfReader);
```

Comment: where are you setting the `Font` in your pdf using ITextSharp you need to use their FontFactory you need to also add pdfcell for example I am writing to my pdf from the datatable hearders in my example 
`PdfPCell = null
PdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk(dt.Columns[column].Caption, font8)));`

Comment: @MethodMan content contains HTML markup with style tag applid to it and i have different lines with different style.How can i use FntFactory.

Comment: can you stringReplace them with string.Empty The ITextSharp has plenty of working examples on their site that's how I figured it out..

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your font with `pdfStamper`. Here is little idea. You can manage with what you need.

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, fs);
PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(1);
BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
pdfContentByte.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLUE);
pdfContentByte.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 8);
pdfContentByte.BeginText();
pdfContentByte.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, "Here is your settings", 400, 600, 0);
pdfContentByte.EndText();
pdfStamper.Close();
readerList.Add(pdfReader);
```

Update:

Change only tag settings. Use before close.

```
pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetFieldProperty("YOUR_TAG", "textfont", 
baseFont, null);
```

Comment: content contains HTML markup with style tag applied to it and i have different lines with different style.how can i achieve it then.

Comment: I have format where i can set different font for each line or suppose there are 4 lines one line have Times new roman and others lines contains Arial So after converting to pdf All four lines are showing alike no difference in it.i am not sure it will be useful for me as your setting font as per Tag.And one more thing FYI my PDF does preserve FONT size but not Font Family.